# Encoding issue when building with mvn

Tags: java, maven-2, character-encoding, intellij-idea

I'm currently working on a Maven plugin that uses JAXB. The problem is that whether I launch a clean install in IntelliJ or in a console, I don't get the same results. JAXB is reading an XML file encoded in UTF-8, which contains special characters.

In IntelliJ, these characters are read without any problem.
But in the console, these characters are replaced with '?' (I can see it if I do a sysout).

I found the source of my problem, but I don't really understand it and I don't know how to solve it: when IntelliJ runs mvn, it adds an extra parameter `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

```
java -classpath /usr/share/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar -Dclassworlds.conf=/usr/share/maven/bin/m2.conf -Dmaven.home=/usr/share/maven -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher clean install
```

When I run mvn in command line, I can add this extra parameter but it will appear *after* the class name:

```
java -classpath /usr/share/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar -Dclassworlds.conf=/usr/share/maven/bin/m2.conf -Dmaven.home=/usr/share/maven org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 clean install
```

In both cases, if I sysout the content of `System.getProperty("file.encoding")`, I get the same value "UTF-8", but a different behaviour.

Of course I configured my pom.xml correctly using a property like this:

`<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>`

I also tried to add a second property named "file.encoding" but it does not help.

My question is: why does the position of this system property change the behaviour of my program, and how can I fix my problem when I run mvn from command line?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code that uses JAXB runs during Maven build, right? Also, why do you think that these characters are read incorrectly? Perhaps they just cannot be represented in console output.

Comment: Yes it runs during the Maven build. I am sure that these characters are read incorrectly because I use the objects unmarshalled by JAXB to produce output files. These files are correct when generated inside IntelliJ, but not correct when generated from the console. Also, if I run the correct command from the console I can see the correct characters in the console output :)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368527/is-there-a-way-to-make-maven-build-class-files-with-utf-8-without-using-the-exte) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/623036/500478), the JVM starts with a default file encoding (usually the system file encoding) which is used every time Readers and Writers are used without an explicit encoding. Overriding the system property `file.encoding` at runtime does not change this behavior, you really have to specify `-Dfile.encoding` when starting the JVM if you want it to be the default encoding.

To fix my issue, I reused `project.build.sourceEncoding` in my Maven plugin (I had this problem in a custom plugin) to override `file.encoding` at runtime, and use this `file.encoding` to instantiate [InputStreamReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) and [OutputStreamWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#OutputStreamWriter%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) with an explicit encoding as 2nd parameter.

As resources were correctly copied by the maven-resource-plugin in UTF-8, my problem was gone :D.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try including this XML in your pom.xml file:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.3</version>
      <configuration>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</source>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately it does not help. In fact I noticed that Maven was already using the right encoding, I can see it as an INFO log. I double checked the copied file in resources/, it's correct. The problem happens later, when my maven plugin reads the XML during the generate-sources phase.