# Maven: Source Encoding in UTF-8 not working?

Tags: java, maven, encoding, utf-8

i am converting a project from Ant to Maven and i'm having problems with a specific unit test which deals with UTF-8 characters. The problem is about the following String:

```
String l_string = "ČäÁÓý\n€řЖжЦ\n№ЯФКЛ";
```

The problem is that the unit test fails, because the String is read as the following:

```
?äÁÓý
€????
?????
```

The java class is saved as UTF-8 and i also specify the build encoding to UTF-8 in the pom.xml.

Here is an excerpt of my **pom.xml**:

```
...

<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

...

<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
            <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.15</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.15</version>
    </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
```

Am i missing something here? It would be great, if someone could help me here.

**Update**

Regarding the test code:

```
@Test
public void testTransformation()
{

    String l_string = "ČäÁÓý\n€řЖжЦ\n№ЯФКЛ";
    System.out.println( ">>> " + l_string );
     c_log.info( l_string );
    StringBuffer l_stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    int l_stringLength = l_string.length();

    String l_fileName = System.getProperty( "user.dir" ) + File.separator + "transformation" + File.separator + "TransformationMap.properties";
    Transformation.init( l_fileName );

    Properties l_props = Transformation.getProps();
    for ( int i = 0; i < l_stringLength; i++ )
    {
        char l_char = l_string.charAt( i );
        int l_intValue = (int) l_char;
        if ( l_intValue <= 255 )
        {
            l_stringBuffer.append( l_char );
        }
        else
        {
            l_stringBuffer.append( l_props.getProperty( String.valueOf( l_char ), "" ) );
        }
    }
    c_log.info( l_stringBuffer.toString() );
    byte[] l_bytes = l_string.getBytes();
    byte[] l_transformedBytes = Transformation.transform( l_bytes );
    assertNotNull( l_transformedBytes );

}
```

The following logic isn't really relevant(?) because after the first sysout the before mentioned "?" are printed instead of the correct characters (and therefore the following tests fail). There is also no use of a default platform encoding.

The test converts each character according to the TransformationMap.properties file, which is in the following form (just an excerpt):

```
Ý=Y
ý=y
Ž=Z
ž=z
°=.
€=EUR
```

It should be noted that the test runs without any problem when i build the project with Ant.

Comment: What is the test code? Does it use the platform default encoding at any place? Or does the code under test do that somewhere?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make maven build class files with UTF-8 without using the external JAVA\_TOOL\_OPTIONS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368527/is-there-a-way-to-make-maven-build-class-files-with-utf-8-without-using-the-exte)

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: I updated my posting.

Comment: @softandsafe: that's not a useful test, because if your output console isn't set to use a unicode encoding, then the output will look wrong, even if `l_string` contains the correct data (i.e. even if it is compiled correctly). Do you have an actual **assert** that fails? Or do you just verify visually if it works?

Comment: @JoachimSauer: I updated my post again. I have an actual assert that fails.

Comment: @Danack: Thank you, but the solutions in the possible duplicate do not change the behavior.

Comment: From the possible duplicate "It is not enough to define that property. You MUST pass it inside the appropriate plugins. It won't go by magic inside there." But you aren't passing the property into the compiler plugin.

Comment: Looks very much like the java source is in Windows Latin-1 (Cp1252). Test with JEdit or so, try `\u....` as in the answer below.

Comment: @Danack: If you mean by "pass it inside the appropriate plugins" to include the "<encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>" tags in the maven compiler plugin and the maven resource plugin: I did that. Oddly enough, if i use the "export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" (or set instead of export in Windows) line before doing mvn clean install the test runs without any error.

Comment: How about updating the maven config in your question to show the option being set for the plugins?

Comment: @Danack: Sorry, updated my post now.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

I have found a "solution" myself:

I had to pass the encoding into the maven-surefire-plugin, but the usual

```
<encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
```

did not work. I still have no idea why, but when i pass the command line arguments into the plugin, the tests works as they should:

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.15</version>
      <configuration>
        <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
      </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Thanks for all your responses and additional comments!

Comment: That's really odd. The surefire plugin shouldn't care about this at all. Did you use `mvn help:effective-pom` on the broken module to see which options are passed to surefire?

Comment: I did. `<plugin>  
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>  
        <version>2.15</version>  
        <executions>  
          <execution>  
            <id>default-test</id>  
            <phase>test</phase>  
            <goals>  
              <goal>test</goal>  
            </goals>  
            <configuration>  
              <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>  
            </configuration>  
          </execution>  
        </executions>  
        <configuration>  
          <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>  
        </configuration>  
      </plugin>`

Comment: :-/ Why are there two `<configuration>` elements? Is that on Windows, Mac or Linux?

Comment: To be honest, i have no idea. It is on Windows, but i will try to build the project later on Linux.

Comment: I'm wondering what the default encoding is; probably `cp15xx`. Try this: Remove the `-Dfile.encoding` and print the result of `Charset.defaultCharSet()` in your test. I'm also wondering why it matters; the code is compiled with the compiler plugin; surefire should be independent of the compile step.

Comment: `windows-1252`. It seems to use the OS default encoding, but the encoding is set everywhere in the pom file to UTF-8 even in the surefire-plugin.

Comment: Ah, now it makes sense. Set `forkMode` to `once`. That should fix it.

Comment: Hm :-/ I just noticed that "once" is the default. Still, the default encoding should not have any impact on compiled Java code. There must be something else that we're missing.

Comment: I also have test cases with unicode, and when I run maven with Java 1.6 I need to set this argument. While with java 1.7 it's not necessary to set.

Comment: Maybe a bit more resilient solution would be
`<argLine>-Dfile.encoding=${project.build.sourceEncoding}</argLine>`

Comment: This is still open. Issue moved from codehaus to apache at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-951

Comment: Saved my day, man! It took me like 2 hours to figure out the root of my problem (tests were running perfectly fine from IntelliJ IDEA, but one test always failed from Maven). The reason was a literal string in Cyrillic was passed properly (as UTF-8) into myBatis mapper when run from IDEA, but wrongly (as Cp-1251) when run with Maven. Adding Surefile plugin configuration into POM file and specifying argline did the trick!

Comment: The [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-951)  is marked as Solved but as the last comment states, it's still occurring. I have it in version `3.0.0-M4`. This fixed it.

Comment: while this does solve the issue for encoding, I'm not getting any code coverage shown anymore when I overwrite the configuration -> argLine

Comment: as just commented: This change breaks other functionality. So you must write  <argLine>@{argLine} -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>

Answer (score 10):

1. When debugging Unicode problems, make sure you convert everything to ASCII so you can read and understand what is inside of a String without guesswork. This means you should use, for example, `StringEscapeUtils` from [commons-lang3](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) to turn `ä` into `\u00e4`. That way, you can be sure that you see `?` because the console can't print it. And you can distinguish " " (`\u0020`) from " " (`\u00a0`)

   In the test case, check the escaped version of the inputs as early as possible to make sure the data is actually what you expect.

   So the code above should be:

   ```
   assertEquals("\u010d\u00e4\u....", escape(l_string));
   ```
2. Make sure you use the correct encoding for file I/O. Never use the default encoding of Java, always use `InputStreamReader`/`OutputStreamWriter` and specify the encoding to use.
3. The POM looks correct. Run `mvn` with `-X` to make sure it picks up the correct options and runs the Java compiler using the correct options. `mvn help:effective-pom` might also help.
4. Disassemble the class file to check the strings. Java will use `?` to denote that it couldn't read something.

   If you get the `?` from `System.out.println( ">>> " + l_string );`, this means the code wasn't compiled with UTF-8 or that the source file was maybe saved with another Unicode encoding (UTF-16 or similar).

   Another source of problems could be the properties file. Make sure it was saved with ISO-8859-1 and that it wasn't modified by the compilation process.
5. Make sure Maven actually compiles your file. Use `mvn clean` to force a full-recompile.

Answer (score 6):

I had a really resilient problem of this kind and setting environmental variable

```
MAVEN_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is not the encoding of the source file (and therefore the String inside your class file) but the Problem is the encoding of `System.out`'s implicite `PrintStream`. It uses `file.encoding` which represents the System encoding, and this is in Windows the ANSI codepage.

You would have to set up a `PrintWriter` with the OEM code page (or you use the class which is intended for this: [Console](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html)).

See also various bugs around this in: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4153167

Answer (score 4):

this works for me:

```
...
 <properties>
        **<project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.reporting.outputEncoding>**
    </properties>
...
  <build>
    <finalName>Project</finalName>

    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
          **<encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>**
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Following works for me without any issues:**

```
       <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <test>com.testsuite.JunitTestSuite</test>
            <argLine>${argLine} -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```