# French letter encoding from SQL data file for H2

Tags: java, sql, eclipse

I am writing a Junit test where I have this assert:

```
assertThat(foo.getLabel()).isEqualTo("Numéro");
```

I am running this test on H2 from a data.sql file 
Everything is encoded in Cp1252 (eclipse, java files, and the sql data file)
but the assert fails 
I tried to convert all to UTF-8 nothing worked, any help would be so much appreciated!
Edit:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If UTF-8 dosent work you can change your string with special caracter code

é ---> `&eacute;`

```
assertThat(foo.getLabel()).isEqualTo("Num&eacute;ro");
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, actually the problems comes from foo.getLabel()

Comment: the expected part in the assert is fine but somehow the "é" present in the sql file is not correct

Comment: can you print the result of foo.getLabel() ?

Comment: also you'd better do "Numéro".isEqualTo(foo.getLabel()) to avoid nullPointerException

Comment: if you use maven you can see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17656475/maven-source-encoding-in-utf-8-not-working

Comment: @KhalilM did you found the solution ?