# How to make a symbol appear in Netbeans output for Maven project?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, unicode, utf-8

I have tried all kinds things but nothing is working.
Netbeans is always displaying a " ? " instead of the symbol itself ♤ ♡ ♢ ♧

My project is encoded UTF-8.

I changed to font for the Output window to Segoe UI Symbol.
It's still printing < ? >

My code:

[image: Screen shot of code]

Comment: I updated my answer based on your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to specify a font for the **Output** window that can render the characters "♤ ♡ ♢ ♧". One such font is **Segoe UI Symbol**, and to set that as the font in the **Output** window:

- **Tools > Options > Miscellaneous >** click the **Output** tab **> Font**
- Set the font to **Segoe UI Symbol** and click **OK**.

Then just run your application again, and the characters will be rendered correctly in the **Output** window:

[image: outputWindow]

If that doesn't resolve your problem, please update your question to show your code.

---

Updated on 1/5/20, based on OP feedback:

- Changing the font did not help, and with hindsight this was not necessary anyway.
- The issue relates only to Maven projects in NetBeans. Ant projects don't have this problem.

To render the playing card symbols in the **Output** window:

- In the NetBeans configuration file **etc/netbeans.conf**, append `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to the end of the property value for `netbeans_default_options` (just before the closing quote).
- Save the change and then restart NetBeans.
- The PrintStream used by `System.out` must support UTF-8. This can be achieved in two different ways:

  1. Open the project's properties, and set `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8` for **Properties > Run > VM Options** so that the default `PrintStream` uses *UTF-8* encoding at run time.
  2. Alternatively, in the code create and use a *UTF-8* `PrintStream` instead. See the code below for the details.

Here's the code:

```
package com.unthreading.emojimaven;

import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        String symbPique = "\u2660";
        String symbCoeur = "\u2665";
        String symbCarreau = "\u2666";
        String symbTrefle = "\u2663";

        System.out.println("System.getProperty(\"file.encoding\")=" + System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
        System.out.println("StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name(): " + StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        System.out.println("Charset.defaultCharSet()=" + Charset.defaultCharset());
        System.out.println("Default PrintStream: " + symbCarreau + "--" + symbCoeur + "--" + symbPique + "--" + symbTrefle);

        PrintStream outStream = new PrintStream(System.out, true, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        outStream.println("UTF-8 PrintStream: " + symbCarreau + "--" + symbCoeur + "--" + symbPique + "--" + symbTrefle);
    }
}
```

Here's the output when project's **VM Options** is set to `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8`:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building emojimaven 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) @ emojimaven ---
System.getProperty("file.encoding")=UTF-8
StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name(): UTF-8
Charset.defaultCharSet()=UTF-8
Default PrintStream: ♦--♥--♠--♣
UTF-8 PrintStream: ♦--♥--♠--♣
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 0.717 s
Finished at: 2020-01-05T00:21:16-05:00
Final Memory: 7M/60M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Notes:

- The change to **netbeans.conf** is essential, so that NetBeans configures the **Output** window for UTF-8 during startup.
- The default font for the **Output** window is **Monospaced**. Since that renders the playing card symbols correctly there is no need to change it, at least for the requirement given in the OP.
- There is no need for any special settings in **pom.xml**.

Comment: Did what you suggested. Still not working. I edited my question and showed my simple code.

Comment: @mickyyyyyz OK. [1] My example worked because I created an Ant project. I can reproduce your problem with a Maven project, though I'm not sure what's causing it yet. [2] The SO question  [Maven: Source Encoding in UTF-8 not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17656475/2985643) might be helpful for you, though it didn't help me. [3] Can you post your code as text (not a screen shot), and also your **pom.xml**?