# Netbeans 9 - Print Unicode Characters

Tags: java, netbeans, utf-8, system.out, netbeans-9

With Netbeans 9:

```
Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 9.0 (Build incubator-netbeans-release-334-on-20180708)
Java: 1.8.0_181; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.181-b13
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_181-b13
System: Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; UTF-8; en_EN (nb)
```

I want to be able to print:

```
String text = "你好！";
System.out.println(text);
```

The result is instead:

```
--- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) @ JavaApplication1 ---
???
```

I already added `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to the `/etc/netbeans.conf`, added also to the VM options in configuration. Sources encoding option also set to UTF-8.
No problems with the past versions of Netbeans, here I found no way to display UTF-8 characters.

Which way can I do?

Comment: You need to configure a font for the console that is capable of displaying those characters. Right click in the output window, then choose "Settings" and try a different font.

Comment: Not in this case. Chinese characters can be displayed by the monospace, I did that many times. Furthermore if they couldn't I would see a little square, not a ?. I tried to replace a proper font as your suggestion, just to be 100% sure.

Comment: Maybe it's a Maven problem, with an Ant based project this works fine for me.

Comment: Thank you that was a great hint, I didn't try that. Unfortunately I found out my pom.xml was already OK as suggested here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10375505/3200736 I explicitely defined the plugins and stil doesn't work. Weird.

Comment: This really looks like an NB 9 issue. Running a Maven project that writes Chinese characters to the output window works fine with NB 8.2, but renders the characters incorrectly when running the same project with NB 9. I have set the UTF-8 configurations in NB 8.2 and NB 9. I have also configured both NB 8 and NB 9 to use Maven 3.5.0 (**Tools > Options > Java > Maven Home**) and JDK 1.8. So: same project, same Maven, same JDK, same configuration. The only difference is the version of NetBeans. (No problem rendering Chinese characters for a non-Maven project in NB 9.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Updated on 9/8/21 to note that this solution does not work with NetBeans 12.x releases. See [NetBeans 12 UTF-8 Chinese output with Maven projects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69101857/2985643)*

---

For a Maven application created in NetBeans 9.0 using Java 8 there are three actions needed to get Chinese characters to render correctly in the **Output** window, the first two of which you were already doing:

1. Add `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to the property `netbeans_default_options` in file **etc/netbeans.conf**, and then restart NetBeans.
2. From the **Projects** panel set **{project} > Properties > Sources > Encoding** to *UTF-8*.
3. In the application call `System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF8"));` so that the print stream used when calling `System.out.println()` supports UTF-8 encoding.

It's also worth noting some changes that are not necessary:

- There's no need to select a specific font in the Output window (**Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Output > Font**) since the default font of **Monospaced** works fine. Selecting another font may actually cause problems if it does not support Chinese characters (e.g. **Arial**).
- There's no need to specify `file.encoding=UTF-8` in **{project} > Properties > Run > VM Options**.
- There's no need to specify anything about the project's encoding in **pom.xml**.

This is the code:

```
package com.unthreading.mavenchinesechars;

import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class ChineseChars {

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    System.out.println("System.getProperty(\"file.encoding\"): " + System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
    System.out.println("Charset.defaultCharset(): " + Charset.defaultCharset());
    System.out.println("System.getProperty(\"java.version\"): " + System.getProperty("java.version"));
    
    String text = "你好！"; 
    System.out.println(text); // <<<======================= Fails!       
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF8")); // Essential!
    System.out.println(text); // <<<======================= Works!       
}
}
```

This is **pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.unthreading</groupId>
    <artifactId>MavenChineseChars</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

This is the **Output** in NetBeans:

```
cd D:\NB82\MavenChineseChars; JAVA_HOME=C:\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_181 M2_HOME=C:\\apache-maven-3.6.0 cmd /c "\"\"C:\\apache-maven-3.6.0\\bin\\mvn.cmd\" -Dexec.args=\"-classpath %classpath com.unthreading.mavenchinesechars.ChineseChars\" -Dexec.executable=C:\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_181\\bin\\java.exe -Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\\NetBeans9\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec\""
Running NetBeans Compile On Save execution. Phase execution is skipped and output directories of dependency projects (with Compile on Save turned on) will be used instead of their jar artifacts.
Scanning for projects...

-----------------< com.unthreading:MavenChineseChars >------------------
Building MavenChineseChars 1.0-SNAPSHOT
--------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) @ MavenChineseChars ---
System.getProperty("file.encoding"): Cp1252
Charset.defaultCharset(): windows-1252
System.getProperty("java.version"): 1.8.0_181
???
你好！
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  1.021 s
Finished at: 2018-12-12T18:24:12-05:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

From the **Output**, note that:

- The Chinese characters do not render correctly unless `System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF8"));` is called first.
- The Chinese characters render even though `System.getProperty("file.encoding")` for the project returns *"Cp1252"* rather than *"UTF-8"*:

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I was also setting up the correct parameters on the PrintStream. Your answer anyway brought me to the real issue which is the Scanner. Even if well setup (`Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8");`) is losing UTF8 format for some reason, I'll check why. Thank you!

Comment: @donnadulcinea OK. I have never used it, but there is a method `System.setIn(InputStream)` which presumably works in a similar way to `System.setOut(PrintStream)`. So first create your `InputStream` to support UTF-8, then pass that `InputStream` to `System.setIn(InputStream)` before declaring your `Scanner`.

Comment: You are correct that selecting a specific font in the Output window can cause problems.  But, it seems OK to choose a generic font such as "Monospaced", "Dialog", "SansSerif", "Serif" and you can even set it to Bold or Italic if you want.