# NetBeans 12 UTF-8 Chinese output with Maven projects

Tags: java, netbeans

How do I set the output console to UTF-8 for Maven projects?

This question arose because NetBeans did not decode UTF-8 documents correctly (Nordic characters like **áðíøåú** etc.). By doing some search on the internet I found the solution by setting `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`. Now I was able to view and edit files encoded using UTF-8.

Help -> About now showed

```
Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 12.4
Java: 16.0.1; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 16.0.1+9-24
Runtime: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 16.0.1+9-24
System: Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; UTF-8; en_US (nb)
```

`-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` was set by adding it to the end of `netbeans_default_options` in `netbeans.conf`.

This changed

```
System: Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_US (nb)
```

to:

```
System: Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; UTF-8; en_US (nb)
```

However the output is not showing Nordic characters properly.

If I click the **settings** button to the left (see image below) the Maven options dialog opens, however I don't see where I set output encoding. **Maven Home** is set to *Bundled*.

On Linux (Debian 10) the output works fine without any additional config.

[image: Output window]

**Help comes from comments**

As suggested I first run

```java
System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
```

which displayed `Cp1252`. Why does this happen?

And the second test using:

```java
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;  
...  
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);  
System.out.println("读写汉字");
```

which displayed `????`. Again why does this happen when `StandardCharsets` is set to `UTF_8`?

I tried adding `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to *Project Properties -> Run -> VM Options* and still no change to the output.

The last thing I've tried is to remove `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` from `netbeans.conf` again. Checked Help -> About which again shows `Cp1252`.

I created a file, inside the project src folder, encoded using UTF-8 in *Notepad++* and opened it in NetBeans. To my surprise it showed the correct characters. However this surprise changed to an *ahh* later when I opened a UTF-8 encoded file which was outside of the project. Now the Nordic characters are not displayed correctly. And by adding `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` back to the end of `netbeans.conf` the Nordic characters are showed correctly again. The same goes for the Chinese characters.

Then I run the suggested tests and again to my supprise the output is `UTF-8` from the `file.encoding` property. However the second test still shows `????`.

I did notice one change in the output window. The first line is

```
cd C:\..\NetBeansProjects\..\; JAVA_HOME=E:\\...\\jdk-16.0.1 cmd /c "\"C:\\...\\netbeans\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.cmd\" -Dtest=ubl.InvoiceTest#outputTest -Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\\...\\netbeans\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 surefire:test"
```

The option `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` is close to the end of the line. And if I add `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to `netbeans.conf` the first line ends with *... netbeans-eventspy.jar surefire:test"*. **-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8** is not there. Why is that?

**The Maven project**
The issue I was facing is not directly due to NetBeans. Rather it is the combination of NetBeans and Maven.

- To have NetBeans show UTF-8 encoded files characters correctly the option `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` needs to be added to the end of the `netbeans_default_options` variable in the `netbeans.conf` file.
- To get the output to show Nordic characters the **Project settings** of the **Maven project** needs to be set to UTF-8 (and `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` removed from `netbeans.conf` if set).

This leaves the question of Chinese characters still open.
I've tested with setting the Maven project to UTF-16, UTF-32 and Big5 without success for displaying Chinese characters. Also tried with a few font changes (Monospaced, NSimSun, SimSun, Source Serif Pro, Source Code Pro and Noto Sans) without any luck.

**Thanks to**
[andrewjames](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12567365/andrewjames) and [skomisa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2985643/skomisa) for their effort.

Comment: To confirm the encoding being used, run this: `System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));`. Also, a test, try this: `import java.io.PrintStream;` and `import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets` - and then `PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);` followed by `out.println("读写汉字");`. What happens in each case? You can [edit] your question.

Comment: (1) How _exactly_ did you add `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to your conf file? (2) Another test: add `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to your project properties (typically by going to File > Project Properties > Run > VM Options). (3) What "output" font are you using? Check in Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Output > Font. (4) Please **EDIT** the question, instead of adding comments for these things - your notes belong in the question.

Comment: Don't add `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to VM properties. Add `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`.

Comment: A couple of points: [1] This is happening because you have a Maven project. Chinese characters can be written to the Output window without taking any special action at all with Ant projects. [2] The accepted answer to [Netbeans 9 - Print Unicode Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53257763/2985643) solves your exact problem on NetBeans 9, but unfortunately that solution does not work with NetBeans 16.

Comment: Also, I made some minor edits to the OP to reflect that this issue specifically relates to Maven projects writing Chinese characters to the Output window on NetBeans 12.4.

Comment: @skomisa - sorry if I confused things. The Chinese characters were my characters. The question does not show the actual characters which failed to be displayed. Those are not Chinese - probably just accented Latin. My Chinese was more for testing: "if it works with these, then it should work with yours".

Comment: @andrewjames OK, I did not realize that, but no problem. My primary aim was to clarify that the issue was specific to Maven projects. I tested with Chinese text on NB 16, so the post is still accurate, but it would be helpful if the OP updated the question to provide some sample text. I also tested with some simple German text and even that did not render correctly in the Output window.

Comment: I suspect this issue is related to the version of `exec-maven-plugin` being used, rather than NetBeans itself. See open bug [useMavenLogger breaks nōn-ASCII characters (i.e. 99.9̅% of Unicode)](https://github.com/mojohaus/exec-maven-plugin/issues/158). Rendering non ASCII characters in the Output window for Maven projects worked fine with `exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0` in NetBeans 9, but NetBeans 16 is using `exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0`.

Comment: Suggestion: If this is not a duplicate question, you can [write your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), to help future visitors to this question. (Final thought: Bear in mind that not all fonts contain every possible character/symbol/glyph - so, even if that is not the problem in this specific Maven-related case, it's worth checking which font you are using to display your output.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution applies to the initial issue with Nordic characters and leaves the question of Chinese characters still open.

- To have NetBeans show UTF-8 encoded files characters correctly the option `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` needs to be added to the end of the `netbeans_default_options` variable in the `netbeans.conf` file which is located in the NetBeans installation folder under `/etc`.
- To get the output to show Nordic characters correctly the Project settings of the Maven project needs to be set to `UTF-8` (and `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` removed from `netbeans.conf` if set). This can be done by right clicking the project and selecting **Properties**. Click the **Sources** category. There you can choose which **Encoding** to use. This setting applies to the current project.