# Netbeans: UTF-8 characters Chinese Japanese (CJK) text do not print in Netbeans 20 (Java MAVEN) Output window

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, output, cjk

This is my Code:

```
package hello.learningjava;

public class NewClassTEST {

    public static String aMadeUpString() {
    
        return ("Holy moly cow, 你好 よくできました！");
    }
}
```

[Image of the code](https://github.com/i-Gits/Language/assets/157287055/552cc3fb-75f3-48e8-94fd-75b5ca64c9ea)

In main:

```
NewClassTEST b = new NewClassTEST();
String TEST = b.aMadeUpString();
System.out.println(TEST);`
```

Output:
`Holy moly cow, ?? ????????`

[What the output window shows](https://github.com/i-Gits/Language/assets/157287055/b2fa5055-4b2e-4757-bcc6-bed93997aa56)

Expected Output:
Print
`Holy moly cow, 你好 よくできました！`
in the Output Window (Clearly displaying CJK)

< --- attempts --- >

Tried following along some of the [Stackoverflow answers in here - Netbeans 9 - Print Unicode Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53257763/netbeans-9-print-unicode-characters).
Also tried looking into this user's question -
[Stackoverflow : NetBeans 15 Hindi Character Display Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73950077/netbeans-15-hindi-character-display-issue)

Note: I opened an issue for myself in Github and what is written here is what I wrote there as well.

Tried adding

`-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` &
`-J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=On`

at the end of

> netbeans.conf
> located in `C:\Program Files\NetBeans-20\netbeans\etc`

[image: C:\Program Files\NetBeans-20\netbeans\etc](https://github.com/i-Gits/Language/assets/157287055/5860a3cf-9e0e-417c-b7dd-7d2f0e018bd0)

[image: Opened .conf in Notepad++](https://github.com/i-Gits/Language/assets/157287055/89cdacd6-d1ea-4dc4-8f08-de4070c4228b)

[image: Added at the end of the code line](https://github.com/i-Gits/Language/assets/157287055/1ce5afba-d312-4f01-8007-2dfc4356a546)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55112673/newly-installed-fonts-do-not-appear-in-netbeans)

I couldn't follow along every point in the first Stackoverflow link but here's what I have been able to try:

Added code and results:
[image: Netbeans IDE](https://github.com/i-Gits/Language/assets/157287055/cb1a3f58-cf53-4747-8c89-6e0634ae1586)

(Netbeans' hints)
Imported the following:
[image: import](https://github.com/i-Gits/Language/assets/157287055/d6f509c1-2eab-4ee7-9d90-027949c0694a)

Result:
[image: Result in Output Window](https://github.com/i-Gits/Language/assets/157287055/cef402cf-4c6d-4b0e-9f1a-62e8bc2b82ee)

No longer
`??????`
but now it is:
 `ä½ å¥½ ã‚ˆã��ã�§ã��ã�¾ã�—ã�Ÿï¼�`

<--- . --->

I've been looking for solutions since yesterday. It's been hours and I can't seem to find a resolution.

I made sure to restart Netbeans with every edit to the settings, `tools>options>fonts...` or config.
I tried finding other questions of similar nature here but none of them have worked so far.

I tried installing various fonts and switching fonts. (Although what I downloaded were `.otf`, not `.ttf`)
Tried importing new font .zip files (Noto JP, Noto Emoji)

Tried Monospace, Courier, Noto JP, Noto Emoji, Arial in both the `MISCELLANEOUS > OUTPUT > FONT` and `TOOLS>OPTIONS>FONTS & COLORS`.
Note: `Courier` displays CJK text in the editing window, but not in the Output window.

I have restarted my PC several times.

I am new to programming so some of the possible solutions like

> 2. From the Projects panel set {project} > Properties > Sources > Encoding to UTF-8.

from user skomisa, I could not execute. I'm not sure how to go about doing this. I tried looking online on how to find properties in the projects panel set, could I also be guided on how to do this?

If you know any other way to solve this, please let me know.
Thank you!

---

**[ EDIT 20240217 1835 ]**

- *Java Version 8 Update 51*

*(build 1.8.0_51-b16)*

- Netbeans 20
- Windows 10

Comment: Here is [My Github Issue -- With visible supporting images/screenshots](https://github.com/i-Gits/Language/issues/2)

Comment: Can you post a link to the *actual source code* (the .java file)? Amd

Comment: And in the meantime show output of `return "\u4F60\u597D\u0020\u3088\u304F\u3067\u304D\u307E\u3057"`;

Comment: See code from [Comment by g00se](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77976307/netbeans-utf-8-characters-chinese-japanese-cjk-text-do-not-print-in-netbeans#comment137469136_77976307) run [at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/tVth67).

Comment: State the basics: What version of Java running in what version of what IDE on what version of what host OS.

Comment: Here's my source code! (NewClassTEST.java) https://ideone.com/nRUf8e (and here is my main class https://ideone.com/LhnNTL) (LearningJava.java) EDIT: Oh! Here's my other class https://ideone.com/AwjNZR (Animal.java)

Comment: What happened with my suggestion?

Comment: Hi, g00se! **Suggestion output:**  It returns empty boxes [ EDIT: also, I edited my post to add 1.) **Java Version** 2.) **IDE Version** and 3.) **OS Type**

Comment: That suggests lack of font support. In *what* are you seeing those empty boxes?

Comment: The output window of Netbeans IDE v20 _ Windows 10 _ Java v8.51 (Please do clarify if I understood your question incorrectly.)

Comment: What font is set?

Comment: Tried Monospace, Courier, Noto JP, Noto Emoji, Arial in both the output and edit window. (i.e. [ MISCELLANEOUS > OUTPUT > FONT ] and [ TOOLS>OPTIONS>FONTS & COLORS. ] )

Comment: Can you first try with the less exotic `System.out.println("\u20ac");`